# DOMXpath | Select the innermost divs

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

Im looking for a way to select the innermost div with PHP

for example:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            -
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                -
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `DIV`'s containing the `-` would be selected in the `NodeList`

Im using DOMDocument and DOMXpath to go threw the html, heres and example of what one of my methods so you can see the way my class is created.

```
public function getkeywords()
{
    foreach($this->Xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@content][@name="keywords"][1]') as $node)
    {
        $words = $node->getAttribute('content');
        if($words)
        {
            return explode(',',str_replace(array(", "," ,"),",",$words));
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;       
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Im looking for a way to select the
>   innermost div

That should be:

```
//div[not(descendant::div)]
```

Comment: Hmm, that one is indeed better than mine +1 *(deleting mine)*.

Comment: Do note that this is the only case where `.//` notation is really needed: i.e. `//div[not(.//div)]`