# Jsoup Select only innermost divs

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Is there a way to select only innermost divs (i.e. divs that do **not** contain other divs) in Jsoup?

To clarify: I am referring to divs only. That is, if a div contains elements that aren't divs but it doesn't contain any div, it is considered (for my case) an "innermost div".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jsoup works with CSS selectors. But what you want is not possible with a CSS selector. So this is out of question. You'd need to examine every single div in a loop.

```
Elements divs = document.select("div");
Elements innerMostDivs = new Elements();

for (Element div : divs) {
    if (div.select(">div").isEmpty()) {
        innerMostDivs.add(div);
    }
}

// ...
```

Comment: AFAIAC you are *the* expert on Jsoup. If you say there isn't a single expression in JSoup to do this (as there is in [PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010274/domxpath-select-the-innermost-divs)), then I should look no further. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Admittedly, I first tried with `document.select("div:not(>div)")` to see if Jsoup doesn't have an sneaky trick builtin to make that to work. But, unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a selector like `div:not(:has(div))` -- i.e. "find divs that do not contain divs".

```
Elements innerMostDivs = doc.select("div:not(:has(div))");
```